# hasManyThrough relations ships with join?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 4 tables (`Cars`, `Vignettes`, `Inspections` and `Insurances`). Vignettes, Inspections and Insurances are "belongsTo" to Cars.

I need to combine results of these three tables into one query and sorting by 'created_at' and take first 3-4 of them. **How can I achieve that?**

All of the three tables have same column names and types

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain things together, something like

```
$car->with('Vignettes')
 ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc)
 ->take(4)
 ->get();
```

As with everything laravel, [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) are your friend.

Comment: I tried this: 

Car::find(1)->with('vignettes', 'insurances', 'inspections')
                ->orderBy('expire_on', 'desc')
                ->take(4)
                ->get();

But doesnt work properly.

Comment: Maybe I need a pivot table or just add all of three tables into one with field ' tax_type '